# Does a Javascript bookmarklet have access to browser events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, bookmarklet

Basically, the bookmarklet needs to look at the domain of the site that is being loaded, and if it is one of our domains, pop-up a window for action...

However, most bookmarklets need to be explicitly activated by the user using a click on the bookmarklet.  Is there a way to make the bookmarklet aware of every new window/page loaded by the browser?

Answer (score 0):

No. I would imagine a browser plugin is closer to what you require.

Answer (score 0):

No. (Thank god.. imagine if every bookmark could track the pages you're loading)

This sounds more like something you would write an extension for.